# Why are there only 2 moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

In the [Math.SE 2012 Community Moderator Election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election) there are only 2 moderator positions.
To me this seems to be too few - considering the amount of questions (51,252).

If I understand correctly the User [Experience SE has 3 moderators](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election), and there are less than 5000 questions in total.

So, can someone explain why are there only two moderators on Math.SE? Why not 5, 10 or 20?

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979/is-it-time-to-expand-the-moderator-team and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/2012-community-moderator-election

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks.

Comment: The total number of questions doesn't strike me as relevant; the moderator workload is mostly determined by the number of questions per unit time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are [currently four moderators](https://math.stackexchange.com/about) (Qiaochu, Willie, Mariano, and myself), and the two winners of the election will be *added* to make a total of six.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that!

Comment: When I think about it - six persons are not *that* many either... :)